# Passing record id In the List Button (URL type)

Tags: lightning-web-components, list-button

I had created a list button and from that button I am calling the lwc component.I want to pass the parent object Id to that LWC component from that list button.
URL -->
/one/one.app?strRecordId=?#xyzuybnsbdbkfkfnsknfksfnlsfl==

What should I replace ? with  because button is on list view and I can get related record field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onto the related list button you need to update the URL

> ParentObject.Id

Like this

> URL --> /one/one.app?strRecordId={!CASESAFEID(ParentObject.Id)}#xyzuybnsbdbkfkfnsknfksfnlsfl==

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thank you it worked!